# XSD my data type

Tags: xsd

I would like to ask about .XSD document. I cannot find anything about creating my own type, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:complexType name="Client">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="string"/>
            <xs:element name="SecondName" type="string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="Contact">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="contacts" type="Client"  minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>   
</xsd:schema>
```

And I would like to know is that right way to define my own type contact?

Comment: Looks fine - the only thing I'd change is to swap the `Contact` and `contacts` element names because your complex type is a list of contacts and your element of type `Client` is a single contact.

Comment: Thank's a lot this is my first experience with that so I was not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points that were not quite right.

- The xsd: namespace alias on the closing schema tag should be just xs:
- The primitive string types need there types qualifying, ie xs:string.
- From a style point of view ComplexTypes should end Type.
- If you want to use the schema (presumably via the Contact) then you need to declare a root element.

[image: Graphical representation of an XML Schema]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created with Liquid XML Studio 2012 Developer Edition (Trial) 10.0.1.3941 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com)-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="ClientType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="SecondName" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ContactType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="contacts" type="ClientType" minOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:element name="Client" type="ClientType" />
</xs:schema>
```

Basically XML Schemas are complex things to write without a tool. I'd seriously look into getting a good schema designer, I'd recommend [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/Xml-Schema-Editor.aspx).